# unable to to get names from dropdown list in the text box

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have got a page where I am generating textboxes and dropdown list dynamically. I am trying to choose a name from dropdown list then show it in the textbox next to it. The problem is I am able to do that only for the first row I mean I am able to choose a name from the first dropdown list then show it in the text box next to it. But I am not able to do that for others. Can you please help?

Here is my code

Please Note: I am using JavaScript to show what the user chooses from DropDown list and show it in the 
             textbox

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['team'])){
         $selectedTeam = $_POST['team'];
         $selectedWeek = $_POST['week'];

        //getting team member names from resolver table 
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `names` WHERE `teamName` = '$selectedTeam'";
        $query_run_teamName = mysql_query($query);
         while($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run_teamName)){
            $verNAME[]  = $query_row['verNAME'];
        }//end of while
    }//end of if condition
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Option Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="roster.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">

        //Function below gets ID and assigns value to the left text field
        function getValue(RightTextfield, leftTextfield){
                var TextfieldValue     = _(RightTextfield).value;   
                _(leftTextfield).value = TextfieldValue;
        }//end of getValue() function 

        function _(x){
             return document.getElementById(x);
        }//end of _(x) function 
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div id="wrapper">
        <form action="teamRoster.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
            <div id="response"></div><!--End of response Div-->
            <?php

               for ($i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++) {
                    echo '<div class="STeam">';

                    //code below to generate Text Fields dynamically 
                    echo '<input type="text" id="r1Value1" name="r1Value1">';

                        //code below to generate dropdown list dynamically 
                        echo '<select id="ChooseMember" name="ChooseMember" onchange="getValue(\'ChooseMember\', \'r1Value1\')">';      
                        echo '<option value="">Select Team Member</option>';
                                foreach ($verNAME as $key) {
                                    echo '<option value="'.@$key.'">'.@$key.'</option>';
                        }
                        echo '</select>';
                    echo '</div>';
                }//End of for loop
             ?>
            <!--Passing week and team name as hidden values-->
            <input type="hidden" id="HiddenDay" name="HiddenDay" value="<?php echo $selectedWeek;?>">
            <input type="hidden" id="HiddenTeam" name="HiddenTeam" value="<?php echo $selectedTeam;?>">
        </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank You

Comment: You have `name="HiddenTeam" value="<?php echo $selectedTeam` yet you are using `$selectedTeam = $_POST['team']` your POSTs don't match. Check the others.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you should check your select box ID and name. You input same ID and name in your select box. My suggestion is to append value of $i with selectbox ID and name (specially with ID for javascript, but you should append into name due to grab value from PHP)

```
For select box HTML -
<select id="ChooseMember_<?=$i?>" name="ChooseMember_<?=$i?>" onchange="getValue(\'ChooseMember_<?=$i?>\', \'r1Value1\')">
```

This problem is creating for same ID and name of select box.